# Error while adding items to a list with a wildcard

Tags: java, list, generics, compiler-errors, wildcard

```
private static Map<String, List<?>> eventsMap = new HashMap<>();

public static void logEvent(String eventIdentifier, Class<?> event) {
    if (!eventsMap.containsKey(eventIdentifier)) {
        eventsMap.put(eventIdentifier, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    eventsMap.get(eventIdentifier).add(event);
}
```

I'm trying to make a logging class that has the option to log events. For that purpose I used a Map that links an identifier to a List of events. I want to be able to put any type of object in the list, but once the type of list is determined, all the next items added to the list have to conform to the first type. For example:

```
    LogWriter.logEvent("date", "0:00:01");
    LogWriter.logEvent("date", "0:00:02");
    LogWriter.logEvent("date", "0:00:03");

    String[] a = {"street", "zipcode", "housenumber", "city"};
    String[] b = {"street", "zipcode", "housenumber", "city"};
    String[] c = {"street", "zipcode", "housenumber", "city"};

    LogWriter.logEvent("address", a);
    LogWriter.logEvent("address", b);
    LogWriter.logEvent("address", c);
```

But I get a compile error at the

`eventsMap.get(eventIdentifier).add(event);`

```
no suitable method found for add(Class<CAP#1>)
    method Collection.add(CAP#2) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to CAP#2)
    method List.add(CAP#2) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to CAP#2)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

Please explain why and how I can fix this.

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 3):

You have a wildcard in the declaration for `eventsMap`:

```
private static Map<String, List<?>> eventsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

This means that the `List`s stored as values in your map could be lists of anything.  But that doesn't mean that anything can be stored in it.  It is a list of a specific yet unknown type.  It could be a `List<Object>`, a `List<Integer>`, or a `List<Foo>`.  For type safety reasons, the compiler must disallow such a call to `add`, because it cannot tell if `event` is of the correct type.

Because `event` appears to be a `Class`, replace the wildcard with `Class<?>`:

```
private static Map<String, List<Class<?>>> eventsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

This way a `Class` object representing any class can be inserted into the lists retrieved from your map.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I don't want to insert a 'Class' object into the list, I tried to find a way to get 'event' into the list. 'event' will most often be a 'List' or a 'String' object. At least now I know that 'Class<?> event' as method argument doesn't work, thanks!

Comment: You specified the type of `event` as `Class<?>`.  Regardless, if `event` is a `Foo`, then the type of the `Map` should be `Map<String, List<Foo>>`.